# Create a new grid section in Company Users grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, b2b

I'm trying to add a new section in the Company User grid, accessible through an new filter (next to the existing ones : `Show Active Users | Show Inactive Users`)

The new filter is based upon a custom field that I added `company_advanced_customer_entity`

I see that in `company_users_listing.xml` filters are defined like so :

```
<filters name="listing_filters" class="Magento\Company\Ui\Component\Filters\Status" ...
```

Code:

```
class Status extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Filters {
public function prepare()
{
    parent::prepare();
    $config = $this->getData('config');
    if (isset($config['params']) && is_array($config['params'])) {
        $config['params']['statusActive'] = \Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyCustomerInterface::STATUS_ACTIVE;
        $config['params']['statusInactive'] = \Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyCustomerInterface::STATUS_INACTIVE;
        $this->setData('config', $config);
    }
}
```

but I don't understand how it works, will I have to rewrite `\Status` or should I create my another Filter and put it somewhere in the listing ?

**UPDATE**

In the mean time I added a new `statusPending` state to the native Status:

```
$config['params']['statusPending'] = \Vendor\Module\Helper\Account\Process::CUSTOMER_COMPANY_PENDING_STATUS_PENDING;
```

and had to add it in several places :

- Magento\Company\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerStatus
- Magento\Company\Model\Customer\Source\Status